# Как загрузить код сохранённой html страницы в текстБокс?

Tags: c#

здравствуйте, скажите, можно ли как-то получить код html страницы которую сохранил себе на пк?
пробую так, но не получается ничего)

```
textBox5.Text = File.ReadAllText("1.html", Encoding.Default);
```

файл находится в bin\Debug.

Comment: Что означает «не получается»? Не компилируется? Выбрасывает исключение? Вы ведь не ожидаете, что мы должны сами догадаться?

Comment: И во-вторых, когда вы сохраняли страницу, неужели вы её сохраняли в `Encoding.Default`?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указывать полный путь к файлу, например:

```
string path = @"c:\1.html";
textBox5.Text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default);
```